# What is a quadrant polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

> What is a quadrant polynomial?

I have a question in my Maths book which I have attached below.

> [image]

The book does not mention any such thing as a quadrant polynomial. My teacher also didn’t mention quadrant polynomial while teaching.

Comment: I think what they mean is quadratic polynomial, which is $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ (I'm guessing based on the options given in the question)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Really? What exactly should he type in MathJax?

Comment: @miracle173 It was a generic suggestion. In this case, there is only normal text.

Comment: "quadrant polynomial" is a terminology that surely has to be clarified by the author.